# rearranging equation to match other side

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Ok, I'm part through an induction question, trying to prove left hand side is equal to right hand side by rearranging.

$\frac{1}{16}(4k-1)5^{k+1}+(k+1)5^{k+1}+\frac{5}{16}=\frac{1}{16}(4(k+1)-1)5^{(k+1)+1}+\frac{5}{16}$

I can factor $5^{k+1}$ out of LHS for first 2 terms, but I am unsure how to get this to equal a factor of $5^{k+2}$ as per right hand side?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{1}{16}(4k-1)5^{k+1}+(k+1)5^{k+1}+\frac{5}{16}&=\frac{1}{16}\cdot 5^{k+1}(4k-1+16(k+1))+\frac{5}{16}\\
&=\frac{1}{16}\cdot 5^{k+1} (20k+15) +\frac{5}{16}\\
&= \frac{1}{16}\cdot 5^{k+2}(4k+3) +\frac{5}{16}\\
&= \frac{1}{16}\cdot 5^{(k+1)+1}(4(k+1)-1)+\frac{5}{16}\\
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: ok, so general rule, if you have a constant term with exponent, and factor out that constant from an expression, we add 1 to the exponent? Also, is there terminology for when an exponent that has a sum like $5^{k+1}$?

Comment: Yes, that's the general idea. And no, there's not any terminology for exponents like that.